# Base points and geometric points of schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $k$ b a field and $X$ a geometrically connected variety over $k.$ Let us fix an algebraic closure $$\ast: \text{Spec } \bar{k} \rightarrow \text{Spec } k$$ and denote by $\bar{X} = X \times_k \bar{k}$ the base change of $X.$ Suppose I have a geometric point $\bar{a}:\text{Spec } \bar{k}  \to \bar{X}$, and let $b$ be the composite composite $$\text{Spec } \bar{k}  \xrightarrow{\bar{a}}  \bar{X} \to X \to \text{Spec } k.$$  I have seen it claimed then that the corresponding fiber functors $$(\text{Spec } k)_{\text{ét}} \to \text{ Set} $$ induced by $\ast $ and $b$ are canonically isomorphic.

My question is: **Is this really true?**

For example, if we let $X = \text{Spec } k,$ it seems as this is saying that all the Galois conjugate geometric points are canonically isomorphic, yet this seems false to me, since I would expect that they are only canonically isomorphic up to inner automorphisms.

Comment: What do you mean by the functor $(\operatorname{Spec} k)_{et} \to \operatorname{Set} $ induced by $\overline{a}$?

Comment: Oops, typo! I meant the one induced by $\ast.$ Thanks, will edit.

Comment: The source you've seen claiming this didn't perhaps have a $k$-point $a$ of $X$ and define $\overline{a}$ using $a$ and the algebraic closure $*$? That's the only case in which I would think the isomorphism is canonical.

Comment: @WillSawin It did not, at least from what I can see. The book in question is https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-30674-7 , pg. 16. Starting from "The fundamental exact sequence", and there it says "...The restriction to base points of $\bar{X}$ in the study of $\Pi_1(X)$ yields that $pr_\ast \bar{a}$ agrees canonically with $\ast$ as base points of $\text{Spec } (k).$ "

Comment: @WillSawin A similar confusion arises (to me) on pg. 18, Section 2.4:  where it is written that if $\bar{a}$ is a geometric point of $\bar{X}$ that sits above a $k$-rational point $a \in X(k),$ then the corresponding base point is Galois invariant (i.e. the fiber functor is invariant). This seems to me to be true only if one assumes that the base point $\bar{a}$ is, in fact, a $\bar{k}$-morphism. Do you agree?

Comment: But $\bar{a}$ is assumed to be a $\bar{k}$-morphism, isn't it? That's the only reasonable thing. I'm sure that is implicitly assumed, even if it is not stated explicitly

Comment: @GiulioBresciani I don't think it's explicitly stated. And as Will pointed out, the statement in the main question here seems false, no?

Comment: Well, it depends on whether you assume that $\bar{a}$ is a $\bar{k}$-morphism or not (and I'm quite sure that Stix is making this assumption). If that's the case, then $b=\ast$. So, with the implicit assumption, the statement in the main question is obviously true.